# React Typescript interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I get a problem when making an interface on Typescript!

```
export interface Content {
  uuid?: string;
  brand_id?: string;
  brand_name?: string;
  is_active?: boolean;
}

export interface Pageable {
  sort?: Sort;
  pageSize?: number;
  pageNumber?: number;
  offset?: number;
  unpaged?: boolean;
  paged?: boolean;
}

export interface Sort {
  sorted?: boolean;
  unsorted?: boolean;
  empty?: boolean;
}

export interface BrandData {
  content?: Content;
  pageable?: Pageable;
  numberOfElements?: number;
  number?: number;
  sort?: Sort;
  size?: number;
  first?: boolean;
  last?: boolean;
  empty?: boolean;
}
export interface BrandResponse {
  readonly data?: BrandData[];
}
```

and then i want to get data in react component like this

```
const { brands } = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.catalogs.brands);
const [brandData, setBrandData] = React.useState(brands.data);
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = React.useState(brandData.pageable.pageNumber);
```

then the error exits like this
*Property 'pageable' does not exist on type 'BrandData[]'.*

Comment: `brands.data` --> `brandData` is type `BrandData[]` (see `BrandResponse` interface), so it's an array. That would be like saying `foo = [{bar: 5}, {bar: 6}, {bar: 7}]; let baz = foo.bar;`

Comment: Your typing seems ok. Console log your response if your object has that property or not.

Comment: @MajorProductions it has nothing to do with optional chaining, it's that `brandData` is an array of a type, so the array itself doesn't have the custom properties of the type

Comment: The response I get is all right @pepinillo6969

Comment: It may also be worth pointing out that `brandData` and `currentPage`  are redundant state, which is generally a bad practice unless you really need to have a redundant copy of this information for some really good reason

Comment: why are all your interface properties optional? 
Wherever you are trying to access `brandData.pageable` check if brandData has the right type.